# SSHFS file permissions issue

Tags: file-permissions, sshfs, ubuntu-17.04

I am looking for the right way of allowing multiple users to mount a remote folder on my Ubuntu server to our Macs so we can edit the remote files.

The files in the remote Ubuntu server are all owned and in the group of **root** but I execute the mount command with a different user account i:e the following: `sshfs user1@ubuntu-server:/var/www Documents/localcopy`

Now when I try editing one of the files, the files **do not** save.

**My guess is my local files are not saving because on the server they belong to *root* but I need a flexible way of solving this problem because there are many users attempting to edit these files.**

Previously I would have handled this by giving global permissions to the file but that of course is the wrong way.

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Can you give the logging in user group ownership of the files?

Comment: @jrtapsell: I can but doing that would still lock out the other users